# In Sublime Text, how can I specify the fold level, with keyboard shortcuts, without having to unfold all first?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, sublime-text-2, code-folding

I'm trying to work out how to get code folding working how I want in Sublime Text 2.

I can <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to unfold all.
Then I can do <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to fold all.

At this point, I want to be able to go straight to fold level x (i.e. fold level 2). But if I do <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>, nothing happens.

To get to fold level 2, I first have to unfold all, then do <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>.

How can I specify the fold level, with keyboard shortcuts, without having to unfold all first?

Comment: This [guide](http://wesbos.com/sublime-text-code-folding/) should be helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

In your sublime text keymap, add:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+1"], "command": "fold_by_level", "args": {"level": 1} },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+2"], "command": "fold_by_level", "args": {"level": 2} },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+3"], "command": "fold_by_level", "args": {"level": 3} },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+4"], "command": "fold_by_level", "args": {"level": 4} },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+5"], "command": "fold_by_level", "args": {"level": 5} },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+6"], "command": "fold_by_level", "args": {"level": 6} },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+7"], "command": "fold_by_level", "args": {"level": 7} },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+8"], "command": "fold_by_level", "args": {"level": 8} },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+9"], "command": "fold_by_level", "args": {"level": 9} },
```

Level 1 is fold all. Match the "," in your JSON to work. Done. ;)